# Qt QApplication constructor taking very long time on Raspberry Pie python3 PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I am investigating extremely slow start of a python3 script running on Raspberry Pie and nailed it down to Qt QApplication constructor. To confirm, I have created TestQt.py:

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(argv)
```

It takes 45-49 seconds to execute, e.g.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/test-dir $ time python3 TestQt.py

real    0m48.973s
user    0m0.394s
sys     0m0.106s
```

While it starts, `top` shows very low CPU consumption. I have no idea what can be the cause. Any ideas, please?

Edit: as suggested in a comment by three_pineapples:
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Python 3.7.3
PyQt version: 5.11.3
Qt version: 5.11.3

Edit2: as suggested in a comment by samdavydov:
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3

As suggested on another forum, it may be related to connecting over `ssh -X`. I am connecting to the device remotely, so I can not confirm that. However, afterwards it can repaint its (graphics-rich) window in definitely less than 1 second, so it does not look like a bandwidth issue. As far as I know, it has no physical display connected. Could that be a reason?

Edit3:
I have finally got a device delivered to my desk and the problem is gone. It seems it was caused by VPN communication. Having another display connected directly to the device or not does not make a difference.

Comment: Additional details on specific Python/PyQt5/OS (raspbian?) versions would be useful for people trying to reproduce this.

Comment: What kind of rpi have you got? I tried your code on rpi3 & 4, and it seems to be OK. Although you're not showing any widgets, it could be useful to check whether gpu driver enabled